# Executable not working correctly on Azure after build in new version of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, executable

Here is the deal, I have an azure function coded in C# whose only work is when a text file with data is uploaded to the blob it calls an executable and the resulting files from the executable are stored in another folder of the blob. The executable itself comes from a C++ program whose project was mounted on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

My license to Enterprise expired so I downloaded and setup the project on Visual Studio 2019 community. It is not a very large program and not terribly difficult to setup, it compiled and built without any problem and the executable works just fine by itself in any computer... But when I update the executable in azure and the Azure function calls it, it just crashes. Does anyone knows why and how can I resolve this issue?

The executable is stored in a folder in the virtual machine I use with azure and the Azure function calls it using:

```
    // Process file
       Process p = new Process();
       p.StartInfo.FileName = workingDirectory + "Project1.exe";
       p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
       p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

The code on the executable did not change, the only thing different I can think of is the VS version. I am building the executable in release mode x64 the same way I did in VS2017

Thank you in advance for any help.

Diego

Comment: It can be function runtime. Try to change it to v2 rather than v3

Comment: Any errors about it? Can you print out the directory?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by going to project properties and changing Platform Toolset to Visual Basic 2017 and the SDK to the version I have installed and is now working.

I still don't understand why is crashing when I use the 2019 toolset though.

Thank you all for the ideas.